# Electron Doesn't Return Proper Value From window.open()

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron app  which renders an HTML file with contents along the lines of:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var myfunc = function() {
        var data = "Some stuff to display in another window.";
        var secondWindow = window.open();
        secondWindow.document.write(data);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myfunc();">Open Second Window</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now this works in my normal browser (Firefox) but in the Electron app when I `JSON.stringify(secondWindow);` I get `{'closed': false}` and not an actual window handle (though an empty window does open).

Can anyone shed extra light on this behavior and perhaps a way to achieve the desired result with Electron?

Electron app:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))
  win.webContents.openDevTools({"detach": true})
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `BrowserWindow` and call `loadURL` method

```
// In the main process.
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// Or use `remote` from the renderer process.
// const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote

let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
win.on('closed', () => {
  win = null
})

// Load a remote URL
win.loadURL('https://github.com')

// Or load a local HTML file
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html`)
```

**UPDATE**
Please handle the click event on the main controller:

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
    // Hide current window
    var currWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    currWindow.hide();
});
```

Handle main window hide event to make sure that main window is closed

```
win.on('hide', function(e) {
    showNewWindow();
});


var showNewWindow = function() {
    newWindow = new BrowserWindow(windowOption);
    newWindow .loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/new.html`)
}
```

Comment: This is already what I have in my main Electron app, the issue is with opening a second window from the html file being loaded by it. (I've updated the question to add the Electron app contents)

Comment: @FatalKeystroke I just updated my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

This works in a different way. All your browser windows instances managed by your main process, you need to create new window instance in your main process and set it on top of your current window, or you can reload url in you current main window. If this necessity arise from logic in a renderer process you need to notify your main process (through ipcRenderer.send) to perform some action in main process on particular browser window handle. In your current code you just create one browser window, when you call window.open in renderer process, this new instance detached from main process and cant be controlled.